# run specflow project on emulator from jenkins on mac os x

Tags: macos, jenkins, emulation, specflow

I have created a specflow project using xamarin studio. I have installed jenkins on mac os yosemite. Now, Im in need of running the specflow project on emulator automatically from jenkins.

After browsing the net, i found out that, MSTest plugin can be used to run these tests.
But, as im using a mac system, Im not finding the right way of running the specflow project on emulator.

How do I proceed with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpecFlow can use different Unit Test Frameworks, not only MSTest.

See: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Unit-Test-Providers/

So you could use NUnit on Mac OS X.

About which emulator are you talking especially?

Comment: hi, Thanx for the reply..I am talking about "android emulator plugin" that's available on jenkins.I would like to know, how to run the tests on that emulator

Comment: I know this is a naive question, but still hope you would clear:
On jenkins, how do i give the command to execute using nunit

Comment: @SwathiJayaraman: what you want is not possible.

SpecFlow has no support for running tests direct on Android or iOS.
You have 2 options:
**1.)** put your logic of the application into an portable class library and write your bindings against that

**2.)** test your application trought the UI with Appium or similar tools/library